# How to return screen brightness to default level

Tags: iphone

I accidentally changed the brightness on the iPhone SE ios 13.3   How do I change the screen brightness back to the default level, and if this is impossible, can someone tell me what the default level is?  Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a default single brightness, as default is to auto-adjust relative to ambient light levels.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Settings on your iPhone and scroll down you should see a tab for "Display & Brightness". Tap this tab and you'll immediately see a slider marked "Brightness". There is no default level as such (default is to auto-adjust to ambient light levels) but you can adjust the slider to any level you want.